# Is it possible to install Ubuntu and Lubuntu so that their basic programs are separate but they share programs installed after the main installation?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

I was wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu and Lubuntu so that their basic programs are separate but they share programs installed after the main installation of them both and they share a home folder. I thought it might be possible through use of partitioning but have yet to figure out how.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you just looking for the option of the lighter LXDE desktop environment and tools? Is there some other goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want the lighter DE but I don't want it installed alongside Ubuntu for various reasons.

Comment: This question is either very hard or impossible to answer if you can't explain the "various reasons".

Comment: Yea fair enough. Sorry. First of all the clutter. I also want to be able update/remove one without affecting the other.

Comment: I can think of some ways to hack an installation like you desire, but I think you'd be buying yourself more headaches than it is worth. For example, if you install "conflicting" packages that each have their own /etc/foo file that would be a problem. Sharing /home should be no problem, but I'd dual boot the two distributions; the amount of disk required even by a developer's installation of Ubuntu is really quite small and disks are cheap.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Might just be worth digging up an old 98 pc for Lubuntu anyway.

Comment: @msw Actually you seem to have answered it. I recommend posting an answer with the information you provided in [that comment](http://askubuntu.com/review/close/154858#comment436386_341529).

Answer (score 2):

I know what you are talking,
ans the answer is **YES**. And it's **simple**.
I did, and here is how:

1. Install 'Synaptic Package Manager' (use the 'Ubuntu Software Center').
2. Once installed 'Synaptic', open it and type in the search field 'lubuntu' and mark for installation one of them:
   **lubuntu-desktop** (for full options)
   or
   **lubuntu-core** (lighter)
3. Logout (up right corner), then select it for the next desktop you want to use (click the circle next to your username)
4. Done! From now on you can switch between Ubuntu/Lubuntu whenever you want - All you data preserved!

You might want to adjust a little
according to your experience level.

Enjoy!

Comment: Or, from the command line, run `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core`.